# Clone Grid Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I have a Grid template in XAML CODE:

```
<Grid x:name="gridTemplate>
Childrens...
</Grid>
```

Now I want to place this grid in **LongListSelector** in **foreach** loop:

```
foreach(var item in myList)
{
   clonedGrid= ??? (need clone here my xaml control)
   longlistselector.Items.Add(clonedGrid):
}
```

This works for me for WPF:

```
 public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static T XamlClone<T>(this T original)
        where T : class
    {
        if (original == null)
            return null;

        object clone;
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            XamlWriter.Save(original, stream);
            stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            clone = XamlReader.Load(stream);
        }

        if (clone is T)
            return (T)clone;
        else
            return null;
    }
}
```

**How to implement this in WINDOWS PHONE 8?**

Comment: Why not just add this as an item template?

Comment: Because I need do something in depends of the time. So this is only the way. Now I need convert XAML object to string and I will solve this.

Answer (score 0):

I would make a contentControl, where I could put dataTemplate from resources like this:

xaml

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="MyGrid">
        <Grid>
            <!-- here is your data template, where you can bind to item's properties -->
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
```

cs

```
foreach (var item in myList)
{
     ContentControl control = new ContentControl();
     control.Content = item;
     control.ContentTemplate = Resources["MyGrid"] as DataTemplate;
     longlistselector.Items.Add(control);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you Grid does not have many properties set, then just create method that creates new Grid and pass it as argument your old Grid so you can set all the properties to be same.

```
public Grid CloneGrid(Grid input)
{
Grid temp = new Grid();
temp.Width = input.Widht;
... etc

return temp;
}
```

EDIT:
Another way is to define your properties as `Style` in `App.xaml` and then apply it to the `Grid`:

```
Grid.Style = App.Current.Resources[StyleKey] as Style;
```

Comment: But my grid have a lot of properites and childrens.. This is not the solution